# Obtain full URL address

Tags: php, url

I want obtain full URL adres in php script, tell please, this code always give correct URL?
or maybe in some case, this code give us wrong URL ?

```
 if (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
 $s = "";
 }
 else {
 $s = "s";
 }
 $url =  "http".$s."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Comment: Have you tried it? If yes, what was the result?

Comment: This returns URL current page, but i dont know, its works always correct ot not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget port number. This is full function code to receive current page URL.

```
function selfURL() {
  $s = empty($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? '' : ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "s" : "";
  $protocol = strleft(strtolower($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]), "/").$s;
  $port = ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] == "80") ? "" : (":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]);
  return $protocol."://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$port.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but this is not error? 
     $s = empty($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? '' : ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "s" : "";

Comment: the meaning is understood, only in the ternary operator error :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be fine assuming you are using standard port 80, otherwise you might want to include that as well.

```
$uri = 'http'. ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 's' : null) .'://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Comment: Appreciate your comment but if you find an answer useful, hit the 'This answer is useful counter on left'. And if some answer solves your problem, mark it as answer, this helps other users to figure out what answer worked.
It also improves your acceptance rating, which means more users are likely to help you in future.

Comment: Yes, but I am just 11 reputation, for use button "This answer is useful", need 15 score reputation. On this, i can not change answer level.